# Hide and show the split separator of the devexpress spliter container control

Tags: winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I use the devexpress spliter container and I would hide and show the split separator betwwen the two panels of the split container.

Does anybody have any suggestion to resolve this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The great explanation is provided here: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q334040